# Possible ways to call SOAP service from Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, enterprise-integration, azure-logic-app-standard

I want to call SOAP service from Azure Logic App. The only way I see is to build custom connector and integrate it with logic app. Thought on this is, why should I go with logic app if I have to write my custom C# code (connector) for the same.

Is there any other workaround for the same?

Answer (score 2):

As of now there are no SOAP API connectors existing. Here are the possible ways for having SOAP API workounds that you can try.

1. Use [Custom Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-register-logic-apps-soap-connector).
2. Use [Azure Functions and APIM from our local Visual Studio](https://devkimchi.com/2017/12/11/soap-over-azure-api-management-logic-apps-and-functions/).
3. Making your [HTTP end points SOAP enabled](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51678.logic-apps-make-your-http-endpoints-soap-enabled.aspx).
4. Expose [SOAP endpoints](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/soap-to-rest/?ref=msdn).
5. Import [SOAP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-soap-api#:%7E:text=%20Import%20and%20publish%20a%20back-end%20API%20,Starter%208%20Unlimited%209%20Select%20Create.%20More%20) followed by [SOAP pass-through](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/soap-pass-through/).